# How cancel installation continue in WIX after reboot?

Tags: wix

I have custom installer what run WIX bundle. Now I need restart PC during installation. But I don't need WIX bundle start itself after. Instead custom installer call WIX again (and already installed packgaes will be skipped by DetectCondition)
So question is how to prevent bundle to schedule continuation after OS restart?

WIX version: 4.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Your custom BootstrapperApplication is provided the state of the restart switch so it can tell when it's running after restarting. Your custom BootstrapperApplication can then choose to exit right away.